# FNC1 Character missing in labels printed from Toshiba printers

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, printers, bluetooth-printing

We are having a **mobile application(Xamarin forms-C#)** that prints the labels via a printer connected to the device via bluetooth. So far we were using **Zebra printers** and we were having **ZPL** code to print the **GS1 labels** (Data matrix). The label had few details like GTIN, Price and Expiry date and the data is separated using the FNC1 characters.

We have recently brought **Toshiba Printers BFP-2D**, We are able to print the labels in the Z-Mode using the new printer. However when we scan the printed label, the GS character used as separator goes missing.

Can someone help on how can I print labels  Toshiba printer with FNC1 characters visible when scanning the printed labels.

Please note, we need to scan the labels on other systems so the field separators or Group separators should be FNC1 characters.

string printed in Zebra or toshiba printer: 010033001211238615230928172309153920250\u001d980010

string read from Zebra printed labels: 010033001261533715230921172309183920250\u001d980010

string read from Toshiba printed labels: 010033001261533715230921172309183920250980010

FNC1 character value in the code = "\u001d"

Any suggestion on how to get the Toshiba Printers to print the FNC1 characters as well or if some other character value needs to be passed.